# Duvida com Notação Científica

Tags: c

Existe outra maneira a não ser o com o %E em c, por que fiz desse modo e o uri deu 10 % de erro.
[Link da questão](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1958)

O meu código.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  double teste;
  scanf("%lf", &teste);
  if(teste == -0)
  {
    printf("+0.0000E+00\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%+.4E\n", teste);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tinha postado o código errado, agora está corrigido

Answer (score 1):

O problema está no fato de você imprimir o valor "+0.0000E+00\n" para entradas -0.

Devido a limitação do range de valores que o double pode assumir em casos de números negativos muito pequenos o valor pode ser truncado para -0.0000E+00, com isso o teu if torna ele "+0.0000E+00" o que não é uma saída válida.

Da uma olhada na olhada no padrão [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Formats) para a questão do range e nesse outro link a questão de [+0 e -0](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_negativo).